# Set powerpoint content addin height and width

Tags: javascript, ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins

I am creating a content addin for powerpoint using [yo generator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office). I know I can specify the addin window's height and width in the manifest.xml:

```
<DefaultSettings>
    <RequestedHeight>240</RequestedHeight>
    <RequestedWidth>280</RequestedWidth>
</DefaultSettings>
```

My problem is I want to set the addin height and width based on the ppt presentation slide. I want it to have full size of the slide.
How can I do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you work with contextual add-ins, you don't have ability dynamically re-size requested width or height. You [DefaultSettings](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/defaultsettings) manifest element specify [RequestedWidth](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/requestedwidth), which defines upfront the width of the add-in window. More on [How a contextual add-in displays](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/contextual-outlook-add-ins#how-a-contextual-add-in-displays).

If this is new feature you would like to be added to upcoming release you may post your scenario at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thank for your answer @Slava.